# C# WebBrowser null element on assignment from collection to single variable

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I've worked quite a bit with the WebBrowser navigating DOMs and have not usually had an issue traversing it... maybe it's just too early in the morning:

The MessageBox.Show works exactly as expected showing the correct value:

However the "while" line throws a null pointer exception because 'form' is null (confirmed in debugger).

```
HtmlElementCollection el = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("h1");

MessageBox.Show(el[0].InnerHtml);

HtmlElement form = el[0];

while (form.TagName != "form")
{
   form = form.Parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reached the top level parent without finding a matching TagName.

ie the first 'h1' (your el[0]) on the page is not inside a form.

Comment: omg thanks - I was making the assumption that it was failing on the first iteration... thanks ;-) It is too early in the morning - the tag names are uppercase lol

Comment: Haha, no problem, we've all been there!